# Default browser properties in Selenium

Tags: selenium, browser

What are the default properties of browser when we run any selenium script, like whats it window size, mode, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is firefox profile default prefs from python selenium 2.31.0 firefox_profile.py

Type "about:config" in firefox address bar to see all preferences

Reference to the entries in about:config: http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries

```
DEFAULT_PREFERENCES =
{ 
"app.update.auto": "false",
"app.update.enabled": "false", 
"browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting": "false", 
"browser.EULA.override": "true",
"browser.EULA.3.accepted": "true",
"browser.link.open_external": "2", 
"browser.link.open_newwindow": "2", 
"browser.offline": "false", 
"browser.safebrowsing.enabled": "false", 
"browser.search.update": "false", 
"extensions.blocklist.enabled": "false", 
"browser.sessionstore.resume_from_crash": "false", 
"browser.shell.checkDefaultBrowser": "false", 
"browser.tabs.warnOnClose": "false", 
"browser.tabs.warnOnOpen": "false", 
"browser.startup.page": "0", 
"browser.safebrowsing.malware.enabled": "false", 
"startup.homepage_welcome_url": "\"about:blank\"", 
"devtools.errorconsole.enabled": "true", 
"dom.disable_open_during_load": "false", 
"extensions.autoDisableScopes" : 10, 
"extensions.logging.enabled": "true", 
"extensions.update.enabled": "false", 
"extensions.update.notifyUser": "false", 
"network.manage-offline-status": "false", 
"network.http.max-connections-per-server": "10", 
"network.http.phishy-userpass-length": "255", 
"offline-apps.allow_by_default": "true", 
"prompts.tab_modal.enabled": "false", 
"security.fileuri.origin_policy": "3", 
"security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy": "false", 
"security.warn_entering_secure": "false", 
"security.warn_entering_secure.show_once": "false", 
"security.warn_entering_weak": "false", 
"security.warn_entering_weak.show_once": "false", 
"security.warn_leaving_secure": "false", 
"security.warn_leaving_secure.show_once": "false", 
"security.warn_submit_insecure": "false", 
"security.warn_viewing_mixed": "false", 
"security.warn_viewing_mixed.show_once": "false", 
"signon.rememberSignons": "false", 
"toolkit.networkmanager.disable": "true", 
"toolkit.telemetry.enabled": "false", 
"toolkit.telemetry.prompted": "2", 
"toolkit.telemetry.rejected": "true", 
"javascript.options.showInConsole": "true", 
"browser.dom.window.dump.enabled": "true", 
"webdriver_accept_untrusted_certs": "true", 
"webdriver_enable_native_events": "true", 
"webdriver_assume_untrusted_issuer": "true",
"dom.max_script_run_time": "30", 
}
```

Comment: thanks, can you share the same for chrome browser or how should I find it about chrome browser.